# What does the Sql query ISNULL(@parameter,ColumnName) return, if we pass the null value.?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I want to know the reason behind this code. What will happen if we pass columnName in isNull.

```
@parameter = null,

select txtAbc,* from table where (txtAbc Like (isNull(@parameter,txtAbc)))
```

Thanks in Advance.

Editing this Question to avoid confusions.

I know isNull will return true, In that case query will look like,

```
select txtAbc,* from table where txtAbc Like null
```

In that case, it should not select any row, But in my case It's returning all the rows except the rows containing null values in txtAbc.

I want to know the reason behind this.

When running the code I am getting the output equivalent to 
It's equivalent to

```
select * from table where txtAbc is not null
```

Edited :
PS : Please comment the reason before downvoting :P

Comment: Although ISNULL is a part of SQL Server as well as MySQL but it is a good practice to tag products which you are using :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi what is the good practice then rahul.?

Comment: Already added that in my previous comment. If you are using MySQL then tag only MySQL and not other products. It will help you as well others who are answering(*BTW I am not the one who downvoted incase you are bothered*)

Comment: No, I am not bothered at all, I thought its basic sql and problem can be answered by anybody who uses any product of sql. 
I guess this is the reason why stackoverflow has given a limit of 5 tags instead of 1. 
PS : No Offence

Comment: Guys, who are downvoting the question, please tell me the reason please.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL you need `ANSI` equivalent `COALESCE`

```
select txtAbc,* 
from table 
where (txtAbc Like (isNull(@parameter,txtAbc)))
```

If `@parameter = NULL` you get:

```
select txtAbc,* 
from table 
where txtAbc Like txtAbc
```

which is always true(for `txtAbc NOT NULL`). Otherwise is the same as:

```
select txtAbc,* 
from table 
where txtAbc IS NOT NULL;
```

For performance reason you should use code below because your code is **non-SARGable**

```
select txtAbc,* 
from table 
where txtAbc Like @parameter
   OR @parameter IS NULL
```

**EDIT:**

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), txtAbc VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc'), (NULL);

DECLARE @parameter VARCHAR(100) = NULL;

select txtAbc,id 
from  #tab
where (txtAbc Like (isNull(@parameter,txtAbc)))
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/385903)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦════╗
║ txtAbc ║ id ║
╠════════╬════╣
║ aaa    ║  1 ║
║ bbb    ║  2 ║
║ ccc    ║  3 ║
╚════════╩════╝
```

Comment: I am pretty sure, that you have posted the same answer, what I have also expected. Please run the code in your machine,

`If @parameter = NULL`, It's equivalent to 

`select * from table where txtAbc is not null`

Comment: @Abhii Yes assumed that `txtAbc` was NOT NULL column. Of course you are right because `NULL LIKE NULL` is NULL and not true.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but you can test in following. `@Parameter` declared as `NULL` and you use `ISNULL` to set another value if `@Parameter` is `NULL`, in this example `foo`. So It selecting data where `col` equals to `foo`

```
create table #t
(
   Id INT,
   col varchar(60)
)
insert into #t values (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')

declare @parameter varchar(60) = null

select *
from #t
where col = isNull(@parameter,'foo')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id  col
1   foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISNULL function returns 1 when the value is NULL and 0 when the value is not NULL.

So in your case if the value @parameter is null then it will return 1 and make `txtAbc`. So it would be similar to writing as:

```
select txtAbc,* from table where txtAbc Like txtAbc
```

**EDIT:**

The reason why it is not returning NULL row because when you compare NULL with a NULL then the result is false. So its like

```
if(NULL = NULL)
   print('True')
else
   print('False')
```

output will be `False`. So the row with the NULL value is not returned as per your expectation.

Comment: Will it ignore that row containing null value in the output.? Its Ignoring in my case, I just want to know why .?

Comment: @Abhii:- A better approach to return the NULL value would be to check with NULL value like `txtAbc IS NULL`

Comment: This is what I also thought, please run this query. Its not returning that row, just the reverse of what expected. @Rahul Tripathi

Comment: @Abhii:- Ok I got your point of confusion, actually what is happening is you are trying to compare `NULL like NULL` which is `False`. You can verify it using `if(NULL = NULL)
print('True')
else
print('False')`

Answer (score 0):

expression is a NULL value, the ISNULL function will return 1

expression is not a NULL value, the ISNULL function will return 0

```
mysql> SELECT ISNULL('');
Result: 0

mysql> SELECT ISNULL(NULL);
Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL` as the name says will check if a value is `null` or not.
If its 'null' will return `true` else `false`

Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: That's not right. `Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.`

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas:- Why?

Comment: @RahulTripathi OP says that `ISNULL()` checks whether value is null and returns *true* or *false*. That's not what this function does. I've pasted description from MSDN.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas:- Aah, I took the other way round, I thought you said the MSDN quote is not correct.(I misunderstood it) :(